# Floating Point Number to Null-Terminated ASCII String

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm reviewing for an exam right now and one of the review questions gives an answer that I'm not understanding.

A main memory location of a MIPS processor based computer contains the following bit pattern:

0 01111110 11100000000000000000000

a. If this is to be interpreted as a NULL-terminated string of ASCII characters, what is the string?

The answer that's given is "?p" but I'm not sure how they got that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ASCII characters are made up of 8 bits. So given your main memory location, we can break it up into a few bytes.

1. 00111111
2. 01110000
3. 00000000
4. ...

Null terminated strings are terminated with none other than... a null byte! (A byte with all zeros). So this means that your string contains two bytes that are ASCII characters. Byte 1 has a value of 63 and byte two has a value of 112. If you have a look at an ASCII chart [like this one](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/question-mark-ascii-code-63.html) you'll see that 63 corresponds to '?' and 112 corresponds to 'p'.